# can "more perfect union" mean "less crappy union"?

Tags: comparative-constructions

**perfect** when it is open to degree seems a pretty slippery word. Can "more perfect" mean "less crappy"?  What does "perfect" actually mean when it is a comparative term? Can something that is pretty damn bad be called "more perfect" than something which is about as bad as you could possibly imagine?

Comment: There's an intentional paradox at work—"perfect" *isn't* normally open to degree. Perfect is perfect. There's a lot of profundity packed into this "misusage," or at least bending of usage. And a lot has been written about that particular phrase! To keep us out of the purviews of the philosophy and government SEs, can you edit to focus on universal usage?

Comment: (Also, to be clear, I don't think you can use "more perfect" without creating an allusion to the US Constitution, or at least the possibility of an unintentional one.)

Comment: "more perfect union" is used in works predating the USA, e.g. in discussions of Arianism and discussions of Protestantism vs Roman Catholicism and even about complementary foods, from the early 18th century. It was an oft-used collocation. Not necessarily a contemporary political question.

Comment: @AndyBonner That may be true in the US, but it's certainly not so everywhere else.

Comment: I've always interpreted a phrase like ‘more perfect’ as an elision of ‘**more _nearly_ perfect**’ — not perfect, but closer to being so.  (You can't qualify perfection; as Andy Bonner says, it's an absolute — something is either perfect, or not.  But you can qualify _lack_ of perfection.  It's the same with uniqueness: something can't be more or less unique, but it can be more or less _near_ to being unique, i.e. have more or fewer equals.)

Answer (score 3):

'More perfect' is not something we'd use as a comparative term. We would not say in one breath than one thing was perfect but another was 'more' perfect.

'Perfect' can mean that something is flawless, and arguably you cannot get any better than that. However, it's not the same as a superlative - 'perfect' often just means 'ideal'. Being flawless or ideal doesn't mean something can't be improved upon. For example, a piece of tech like a smart phone could be 'perfect' - fit for purpose, free from defects - yet still be superceded by a better model. Also, 'perfect' is often contextual or opinion-based. What one person considers perfect may not necessarily be what another person does.

Still, you would not hear a native speaker say "more perfect" as a comparative term, ie that one thing is more perfect than another. Any things you were comparing would have to share context and purpose, so it just doesn't make sense. Something is either perfect or not, there are no gradations.

What you may often hear said is that something "*could not be more perfect*". This is an idiomatic way of saying you don't believe something could be improved upon.

Comment: So "perfect" is like the word "refined"?

Comment: @TimR I wouldn't say so: "refined" is the kind of adjective which *does* work well in the comparative and superlative. For example: "Coffee A is good, but Coffee B has an even more refined flavor." "The most refined version of the document is that resulting from our latest edit."

Comment: @TimR Not really - literal *refining* of something, like metal, is a process that can be repeated. You can refine something, then refine it some more. But it's a process that can result in something being 'perfect'. Still, something else can be 'better'.

Comment: While "more perfect" is not really a _correct_ comparative, I think it would still be readily understood by a native speaker.  But it's more idiomatic to use "better", perhaps as in "this is a better fit for my purpose".  The phrase "X is perfect but Y is better" would be understood but is not correct usage.

Comment: @Miral It's one thing to be 'understood' by a native speaker and another to speak like one. I understand people speaking to me in broken English and wouldn't criticise anyone for trying. But if someone asks a question about English on an English language learners site then we got to tell them the right way.

Answer (score 1):

"A more perfect union" is *not* using "perfect" in the sense of "maximally good". In fact, I find at least one example where the union in question is seen as *bad*: George Hickes' 1706 *Apologetical Vindication of the Church of England* says this of [the incident of the golden calf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_calf):

> I believe there never was a more perfect Union, and Agreement in the Church of *Rome*, than among the Communicants of this sinful Congregation, nevertheless it was no Schism to divide from them, because they united in a sin. Their Union was their Crime, because the object of it was highly criminal, and […] [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=1ns9AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA74&dq=%22more+perfect+union%22)]

Rather, "a more perfect union" means roughly "a more united union", that is, a closer or more complete union — not that "more perfect" means "more united", but that "a more perfect X" means "more of an X", and in the case of a union, being more of a union means being more united. (Or at least, that's what "a more perfect union" meant back in the 1700s; nowadays it's mostly only used in allusion to the U.S. Constitution, and not always with its original sense.)

I also find some examples where it refers quite literally to two substances being thoroughly combined, such as a 1745 explanation that fresh eggs have "their oily and saline Parts being in a more perfect Union one with another" than eggs that have sat for a long time [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=fQxgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA260&dq=%22more+perfect+union%22)] and a 1761 explanation that some substances can be [ground together while moist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/levigate) if a "more perfect union is required" than is obtained without the moisture [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=NlNgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA182&dq=%22more+perfect+union%22)].

In the case of the preamble to the U.S. Constitution, the major purpose of the Constitution was to create a tighter union than the [Articles of Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articles_of_Confederation) that it replaced; the Articles of Confederation created a weak central government so as to maximize the independence and sovereignty of the various states, whereas the Constitution aimed to establish "a more perfect union" that bound the states together more tightly, with more obligations and less independence than in the old system. However, modern writers borrowing this phrase often use it to mean "a better U.S.", either by error or by poetic license.